# What database hostname should I use in Google Cloud Platform (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

> First of all, I'd like to say that I am relatively new to GCP.

Currently hosting a codeigniter app with Google Cloud Platform. I already imported my database successfully to Google Cloud SQL. However, when I try to connect, I get the following error: `mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`

Basically, doing the equivalent of PHP's `mysqli::real_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket, $client_flags))`

So my question is, what is the correct hostname/how do you get the hostname for your database on Google Cloud Platform?

### The host name I'm currently using

`your_project_name:your_region:your_instance` where each of those corresponds to my project. I got this information [from the docs](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql). Specifically used the configuration settings listed there and assumed `cloudsql_connection_name: your_project_name:your_region:your_instance`could be used as host name.

Is there something I'm missing?

Also, any tips for hosting codeigniter apps with GCP?

Comment: i hope [this](http://www.hthirukkumaran.com/cloud-computing/715/hosting-codeigniter-on-google-app-engine) should be helpful to you

Comment: Hello there, I could not get it working from the instructions on the link you provided. Thanks for sharing though

Comment: In the Google Cloud Platform Console, from the navigation menu go to SQL and click on the instance name. There you can find the "Instance connection name" which is indeed `your_project_name:your_region:your_instance`. Is it identical to the one you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Use the output of the this command if need FQDN:

```
kubectl exec "your_db_pod_name"  -- hostname --fqdn
```